# What's the best way to detect referrer?

Tags: http-api

I've been searching for some WP specific way to detect any referrer. Have an idea?
I know how to do that in PHP but I just want to know if there's some WP function to do that?

**EDIT:** here is what I 'm trying to test =>

```
$referer = wp_get_referer();
if (  strpos($referer ,'http://wordpress.org') !== false ) echo 'you come from wordpress.org';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to check the referrer will depends of what are you trying to do. You can use  [wp_get_referer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer) or [wp_get_original_referer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_original_referer), but if you want to check the referer for security reasons you should definitely use other functions like [check_admin_referer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_admin_referer), [check_ajax_referer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer), [wp_referer_field()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_referer_field) or other of the [Wordpress Nonces related functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

Comment: thanks, I know AJAX and security functions, already used several times but I was not aware WP can check referer in URL for SEO => trying to achieve some basic detection

Comment: I've edited my thread to be more precise with my question

Answer (score 4):

You can get it using [wp_get_referer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer) and [wp_get_original_referer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_original_referer) functions.

Comment: Ok thanks, was expecting more details (you know kinda wiki) -> but this is this function so

Comment: You can get more information for it from codex pages which i have linked with function names.

Comment: never had to use these functions before, will try.

Comment: Difference between the 2 functions is that if a page post a form to itself `wp_get_referer()` return false, `wp_get_original_referer()` return the original referer. However, note that both make use of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` that, as said in [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), _"Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted."_ @JMau

Comment: @G.M. thanks. I know UA sniffing has some major drawbacks !

Answer (score 2):

use `wp_get_referer();` to Retrieve referer from '_wp_http_referer', HTTP referer, or current page respectively. for more info read [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer)

Comment: Is your answer different from my answer?

Comment: you answered both in the same time

Comment: not too much but we are both writing answer at same time, when i am going to click on submit answer button the notification was appear but i was late, clicked and answer was posted.

Comment: @JMau I thought i have answered a minute before.

Comment: @Anjum It's ok.

Comment: @VinodDalvi no just 5-10 seconds before mine.